# Cannot connect to video session in vidyo?

Tags: c#, vidyo

I cant connect to video session in vidyo getting following errors in the log:

> Blockquote
>   2018-02-12 08:34:37.297 +00:00: ERROR: LmiTransport: [System thread]: LmiTcpTransport.c:1422: LmiTcpTransportConstructAddressFromString: Error resolving address http://127.0.0.1:8888: Undefined
>   2018-02-12 08:34:37.297 +00:00: ERROR: LmiCsWebProxy: [System thread]: LmiCsWebProxyTransport.c:303: LmiCsWebProxyTransportConstruct: ProxyTransportConstruct: TransportAddressConstructFromString failed.
>   2018-02-12 08:34:37.298 +00:00: ERROR: VidyoConnector: Execute Async-0: ..\VidyoConnector.c:2925: VidyoConnectorRunOnAsyncLoginFailureCallback_: VidyoConnectorConnectFailed VIDYO_CONNECTORFAILREASON_ConnectionFailed
>   onfailure called ConnectorfailreasonConnectionFailed

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: 3 down votes for what exactly? At least give a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem. I was running fiddler in the background so it causes WPAD to discover wrong web proxy server. 
I solved it by calling SetWebProxyTransport on vidyo io connector and passing it false or by just closing the fiddler that has solved the issue.